# CSS3 Transition not triggering in drupal

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7, css-transitions

I'm using Drupal 7, and trying to get this simple hover transition to work. I'm fairly certain the code is fine, being as it works when I test it independently. Whenever I plug it into Drupal it appears as expected, but I get no transition on hover. When I inspect element, all the code is there. I have Drupal's ACF turned off, so it's not changing my code. It acts as though it can't read the hover statement.

Here's what I have http://jsfiddle.net/Zod_42/n4y022ha/8/

What am I missing?  Any advise is appreciated.

```
<div class="hapcontain">
    <div class="haplet-h">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/happy-h.png" width="40px" height="40px" /></div>
    <div class="hapbar-h">
        <span class="haphead">Habits:</span> <span class="hapbody">learning and sharing lead to innovation</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hapcontain">
    <div class="haplet-a">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/happy-a.png" width="40px" height="40px" /></div>
    <div class="hapbar-a">
        <span class="haphead">Attitudes:</span> <span class="hapbody">business conducted with integrity and respect</span>
    </div>
</div>


.hapcontain{
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.haplet-h,.haplet-a,.haplet-p1,.haplet-p2,.haplet-y{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background:#3759A4;
    border:3px solid #ABCDE8;
    width:20%;
    max-width:50px;
    padding:5px 2px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hapbar-h, .hapbar-a, .hapbar-p1, .hapbar-p2, .hapbar-y{
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    left:-400px;
    padding:5px 15px 0 65px;
    height:49px;
    max-width:295px;
    background-color:#ABCDE8;
    border:3px solid #3759A4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -o-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
}

.haplet-h:hover + .hapbar-h{left:0;}
.haplet-a:hover + .hapbar-a{left:0;}
.haplet-p1:hover + .hapbar-p1{left:0;}
.haplet-p2:hover + .hapbar-p2{left:0;}
.haplet-y:hover + .hapbar-y{left:0;}

.haphead{font-weight:bold;
    color:#222156;
}

.hapbody{text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Either your markup is different when you drop it into Drupal (for example 'hapbar-h' doesn't directly follow 'haplet-h', or you have CSS included below the style shown above that is overwriting the hover event. Can you do a quick check on both.

Comment: I checked it out, the order is fine, and nothing is being overwritten, but I added this `.haplet-h:hover{background:#0000FF;}` to test the hover state, it works fine. 

These styles show in inspector, but "hapbox-*" doesn't move/appear.

Comment: I figured it out. It was the z-index. The div was hiding behind the BG img.  In other words... I'm an idiot. Thanks for the the help anyway.